# How to proof/disproof this is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this problem :

$T : C \rightarrow R^2$

Proof/Disproof exist a linear transformation such:

$$T(i+1)=(2,-4) \\T(i-1)=(-1,2)$$

I tried to check it using the definition but for $v \in C$ I don't know what $T(v)$ is, I only know for $T(i+1),T(i-1)$

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please state your question more precise. What is given about $T$? Do we have to prove that it's a linear transformation?

Comment: @Jef Laga Edited. Is it understood now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linearity conditions $ T(\alpha + \beta) = T(\alpha) + t(\beta) $ and $T(c \alpha ) = c T(\alpha)$ to find $T(1)$ and $T(i)$ and hence find a formula for $T(a + ib)$ which I think is what you are required to do here.

But more importantly notice that $\{i + 1, i - 1\}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb C$ and there is an important theorem which states there is a unique linear transformation which maps a basis to any set of vectors whatsoever in a given range in a vector space. So as soon as you specify what $T(i + 1 )$ and $T(i - 1)$ you have already *defined* a Linear Transformation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can you explain how I could find $T(1)$ and $T(i)$ in order to use the definition?

Comment: Add and subtract the equations you have. And use the properties of a Linear Transformation I have mentioned.